# Executing code generated by javap -c

Tags: java, jvm

Lets consider following scenario:
`javap -c Test.class > bytecodeTest`
How to execute content of `bytecodeTest` ?

Comment: `java Test`? The .class file contains the executable byte-code. bytecodeTest contains a human-readable view of this bytecode.

Comment: Ok, but lets assume that I would like to do some modifications in `bytecodeTest` and check result.

Comment: Then you need the original source code, or a decompiler. javap is not a decompiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a program to rebuild the byte code from this output, but I don't know of any.

Usually you would use a decompiler if you wanted to compile it later. A decompiler is designed to produce an output which can be compiled. Intellij's built in decompiler is pretty good and even handles lambdas.